# How to resize an image on drag?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, resize

I have a couple of images I want to use in a drag and drop game. I've got this working through the actionscript code snippets but I also need these images to be able to resize by dragging an arrow or something similar at the bottom corner. I can either get the dragging working by not including the resize code and vice versa.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, resize);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging, true);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging, true);
function startDragging(E:MouseEvent):void {
    resize1.startDrag();
}

function stopDragging(E:MouseEvent):void {
    resize1.stopDrag();
}
function resize(E:MouseEvent):void {
    item1_mc.width = resize1.x - item1_mc.x;
    item1_mc.height = resize1.y - item1_mc.y;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I know my image resize code is primitive at the moment but that can be changed to scaling soon enough.

Comment: Is there a reason you have capture set to true?

Answer (score 1):

You have to split your image movieclip (or whatever you have) into two parts - one draggable and one resizeable like that

```
myImageWidget (this is your parent movicelip)
|
|- imageMC (this will hold the image and will be the draggable object)
|- arrowMC (this is your arrow that will be OVER your image and will be used to resize)
```

Then IN YOUR "myImageWidget" you need something like this (get rid of all "this.", it makes no sense :)

```
// image MC will listen for clicks and start dragging
imageMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging, true);
imageMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging, true);

// arrow MC will listen for clicks and start resizing
arrowMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopResizing, true);
arrowMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startResizing, true);

function startDragging(E:MouseEvent):void 
{
    startDrag();
}

function stopDragging(E:MouseEvent):void 
{
    stopDrag();
}

function startResizing(E:MouseEvent):void 
{
   addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, resize);
}

function stopResizing(E:MouseEvent):void 
{
   removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, resize);
}

function resize(E:MouseEvent):void 
{
    // you will adjust this to local coordinates since you are inside of the imageWidget
    width = mouseX;
    height = mouseY;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! That looks like it makes sense and it's now allowing it to drag it wherever I need. The only problem now is the dragging of the arrow which is a separate movie clip placed next to the movie clip I want to resize isn't doing anything. There is no movement and there is no resizing. Got any ideas why?

Comment: You put the arrow movie clip inside the widget, right?  You say it's separate...?

Comment: You might need to do a `stopPropagation()` call to keep the the events that were added later from being called. I can't explain it all in a comment but you can google that. It basically depends on if the arrow and the image are overlapping at all

Comment: What is your arrow ? Is it a MovieClip? And yes, it have to be INSIDE of the "imageWidget", you still want to drag it around with your imageWidget, right ?

Comment: The arrow I've got is a MovieClip. I'm new to ActionScript so I'm not entirely sure what you mean by widget. I've done some googling and there's not a ton of clear information about what a widget actually means.

Comment: At the minute I have a layer on the timeline which has both the arrow movie clip and the image movie clip if that's what you mean by widget. Currently the image can be dragged separately and can be resized by dragging the arrow using your code however there are some slight issues still. The arrow doesn't actually follow the image being dragged around. Keeping the code as just startDrag() means the entire stage moves, not just the images so it has been changed to item1_mc.startDrag(). Also the remove event listener doesn't seem to work, it never stops listening and will resize constantly.Thanks